# Display Magebuzz Category Sidebar Navigation only on home menu

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation

I am currently using the Magebuzz Category Sidebar Navigation with the free classics theme on Magento CE 1.9. I would like to display the sidebar only on the homepage. How can I make this happen. I have been searching for days, but wasn't able to find a solution.

Comment: can post the layout xml of the module?

Comment: There is no layout.xml for this extension. I looked through all the folders and did not find one.

Comment: If it is showing on side bar navigation, then there must be some block called for it.

Comment: <block type="catsidebarnav/catsidebarnav" name="left.catsidebarnav" before="-">
   <action method="leftSidebarBlock" />
 </block>

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the block from layout files so it doesn't show on any page and login to your admin go to `CMS >> Pages >>` edit homepage and from left select `Design` and place the block code there in the left reference. like:

```
<reference name="left">
  <block type="catsidebarnav/catsidebarnav" name="left.catsidebarnav" before="-"> <action method="leftSidebarBlock" /> </block>
</reference>
```